# c# Rest client response error

Tags: c#, restsharp

I am trying to develop a rest client using RestSharp in C#.

Code:

```
var client = new RestClient("url goes here");
var response = client.Execute(new RestRequest()) as RestResponse;

Console.WriteLine(response.ResponseStatus);//Coming as Error
Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);//Coming as 0
```

I am not getting any compilation or runtime exceptions but the ResponseStatus is coming as "Error" and Status Code as "0" in the console.

can you anyone help me understand the reason for this?

Your inputs on this would be really helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: I didn't work with RestSharp but are you sure that you don't need to set anything along with your Rest Request? Like method type, any needed parameters, or user credentials?

Comment: What is the url?

Answer (score 0):

***HTTP response 0 indicates that client could not connect with server and hence forth time out happened.***

which means that you have a problem sending your request to the given URL, either by wrong URL or any other reason and hitting a timeout, this is why you receive status code of 0, which is not a standard HTTP status code.

for standard status code table see:

[Status code table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status).